# this.state is undefined when used in function React JS component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

I have the React component below and I want to access this.state.board (a 2D array with 0 or 1 for each element) from a function randomPosition(). When I call randomPosition it returns "cannot read property state of undefined". Am I doing something wrong with the this keyword?

```
var App = React.createClass({

getInitialState(){

  return {

   board: []

}

},

randomPosition: function(){
//generates a random position on this.state.board array

  var position = [];
  var positionX = null;
  var positionY = null;

  var generatePosition = function(){

    positionX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 64);
    positionY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 64);

    if(this.state.board[positionX][positionY] === 1){

      position.push(positionX, positionY);
      return position;

    } else {

      generatePosition();

    }

  }

  generatePosition();

}


})
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: Ok thanks Felix, let me have a look at that link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `generatePosition function` will have its own scope and hence `this` inside this function will point to its own scope rather than the outer scope where `state` is accessible. You can store the reference of the `outer scope` and then use that inside this function like

```
randomPosition: function(){
//generates a random position on this.state.board array

  var position = [];
  var positionX = null;
  var positionY = null;
  var that = this;
  var generatePosition = function(){

    positionX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 64);
    positionY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 64);

    if(that.state.board[positionX][positionY] === 1){

      position.push(positionX, positionY);
      return position;

    } else {

      generatePosition();

    }

  }
```

Comment: While `this` and scope are related, it's incorrect to say that `this` *is* scope.

Comment: What I said is that `this` will point to the scope of the function, it doesn't mean that `this` is scope

Comment: But that also wrong. "Scope" is not something that can be referenced or pointed to in JavaScript.

Comment: @FelixKling I am running out of words to explain it, could you edit the answer.